# Travel to other countries on a Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen

I have a Schengen visa from Switzerland which I'm touring this Summer

However they gave me a visa for 1 year.

Can I use the same visa to travel to Santorini, Greece (with a 1 night layover in Vienna, Austria)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Swiss Schengen visa to travel to Austria/Greece but you have to pay attention to a few other things than its period of validity:

- The visa should be valid (it's your case as you said it's valid for one year) but also *allow multiple entries* and sufficient length of stay (both are also mentioned on the sticker). For example, if your visa is a single entry visa, you cannot fly to Switzerland, leave the Schengen area and then reenter in Vienna. And multiple entry visas are generally intended to offer the holder more flexibility so it's very important to check whether yours is indeed a multiple entry visas.
- If you show up somewhere completely unexpected, you might be asked why you have a visa from Switzerland and challenged to prove you meet all the other conditions for entry. That's why it's always advisable to first complete the trip you described on your application and then see about doing another trip. Having already entered the Schengen area and left once without incident also increases your credibility.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My visa says ETATS SCHENGEN with MULT and Type C and valid for a year. Im getting a great deal on my miles (which are expiring) to Santorini via Vienna(layover). So was wondering if I can avail that deal , book a trip and show up in Vienna and Greek  Immigration with the same Multiple entry Valid Schhengen visa(an not be ostracized)

Comment: @Robz There should be no Greek immigration. I already covered the rest, I think?

Comment: Thanks again. So after my Swiss trip I can book my tickets to Vienna and Santorini and show up in Vienna airport for my 1 night layover with the same Schengen right.Legally does that work. I was confused if Multiple entry is only visa the same country that issued the Visa or to any Schengen country.Just wanted to clarify that?That would have built my case that I'm making another trip because of my MULTIPLE entry Visa

Comment: @Robz No, it's a Schengen visa and it's for multiple entry in the Schengen area, I just explained that.